# Why does GMail login go through youtube.com?

Tags: gmail, google

For a while I've noticed that Google logins (or, at least, GMail logins) always redirect through to "youtube.com" Is Google handling all logins from youtube.com? If so, why?

(wasn't sure if I should post this on webapps or superuser, so feel free to move this or tell me to move this to the appropriate site if necessary)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you log into a Google site like GMail, Google also logs you into all your various accounts Google accounts - such as YouTube. In order to be logged into a site, Google sets a cookie in your browser.

This is fine for most of their properties which are on the `*.google.com` domain `(mail.google.com`, `docs.google.com`, etc). However a website can only set and read a cookie for it's own domain - `google.com` can't set a cookie for `youtube.com`. To get around this, as part of the login process Google will redirect you through `accounts.youtube.com` to log you into YouTube - and typically your country specific domain if you are outside the US (e.g. I get logged into `google.com.au` as well).

The full login process is described in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230997/how-does-google-global-login-work), it dates from 2009 but most of it should still hold true.

Comment: ah, that makes sense, I had completely forgotten that cookies were handled on a per-domain basis :) thanks!