# Does Google login automatically in Gmail?

Tags: gmail, google, login

Does Google log in/out automatically log in Gmail, if I registered the same Google ID and Gmail ID? And vice versa,i.e. Gmail log in/out auto log in/out Google ID as well?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it does. Logging into almost any of Google's properties will log you into all of them. The workings of this are covered in [this similar question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/30254/why-does-gmail-login-go-through-youtube-com).

Comment: how does this explain the fact that when I open my gmail page it stills askes me to sign in with my id and pw when my google account is logged in? The reason say my account is logged in is coz i have done the sync action, thus in wrench menu/settings/ it appears that my google account is logged in, is that a correct way of judging whether my google account is logged in?

Comment: @frog Not this again. As mentioned [here](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/44298/310) You're logged into sync for Chrome. Those credentials are not shared to your tabs.

Comment: @Sathya this is a different question, why you got mixed up with the other one? BTW, i am not really sure when in the wrench menu/ setting, it says my google account stayed connected, it should mean it's connected, and you claim my google.com account not connected by that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it would do that refer to this one

https://developers.google.com/identity/